# PHP Error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php

I added the following lines to the top of my PHP code, but it throws an error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/reg.php on line 2

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE('CaptchaResponseValue') == "false")
{
    header('location:index.php');
    return;
}
?>
```

I tried: `$_COOKIE("CaptchaResponseValue")`. The cookie is successfully set and is available. Why is it giving me an error when I am using `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: i've been developing in php since almost 10 years yet square brackets missed my eye. This helped thank you.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

It should be `$_COOKIE['name']`, not `$_COOKIE('name')`

`$_COOKIE` is an array, not a function.

Answer (score 17):

Using parenthesis in a programming language or a scripting language usually means that it is a function.

However `$_COOKIE` in php is not a function, it is an [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). To access data in arrays you use square braces ('[' and ']') which symbolize which index to get the data from.  So by doing `$_COOKIE['test']` you are basically saying: "Give me the data from the index 'test'.

Now, in your case, you have two possibilities: (1) either you want to see if it is false--by looking inside the cookie or (2) see if it is not even there.

For this, you use the [isset](http://php.net/isset) function which basically checks if the variable is set or not.

**Example**

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE['test'] ) )
```

And if you want to check if the value is false and it is set you can do the following:

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE['test']) && $_COOKIE['test'] == "false" )
```

One thing that you can keep in mind is that if the first test fails, it wont even bother checking the next statement if it is **AND** ( `&&` ).

And to explain why you actually get the error "Function must be a string", look at [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php). It's about basic creation of functions in PHP, what you must remember is that a function in PHP can only contain certain types of characters, where `$` is not one of these. Since in PHP `$` represents a variable.

A function could look like this: `_myFunction  _myFunction123 myFunction` and in many other patterns as well, but mixing it with characters like $ and % will not work.

Answer (score 5):

Try square braces with your `$_COOKIE`, not parenthesis. Like this:

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['CaptchaResponseValue'] == "false")
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}
?>
```

I also corrected your location header call a little too.

Answer (score 3):

It will be `$_COOKIE['CaptchaResponseValue']`, not `$_COOKIE('CaptchaResponseValue')`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna ascertain if cookie is set...use

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie']))
```

Comment: Because of how the vote-system works. People upvote answers they find more relevant and more helpfull to the question. And people down-vote answers that they find less interesting. I imagine that is why you were down-voted.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg Thats enlightening...it wud be great if these anonymous souls left a comment as to why....but I guess that  is not really a widespread practice :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP.js, $_COOKIE *is* a function ;-)

```
function $_COOKIE(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length).replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
    }
    return null;
}
```

via http://phpjs.org/functions/setcookie:509

Comment: Technically it is but it is converting the cookies contents into an array so in that respect what is called is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

A useful explanation to how braces are used (in addition to Filip Ekberg's useful answer, above) can be found in the short paper [Parenthesis in Programming Languages](http://www.gavilan.edu/csis/languages/parentheses.html).

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
    require_once '../config/config.php';
    require_once '../classes/class.College.php';
    $Response = array();
    $Parms = $_POST;
    $Parms['Id'] = Id;  

        $Parms['function'] = 'DeleteCollege';
        switch ($Parms['function']) {
        case 'InsertCollege': {
            $Response = College::InsertCollege($Parms);
            break;
        }
        case 'GetCollegeById': {
            $Response = College::GetCollegeById($Parms['Id']);
            break;
        }
        case 'GetAllCollege': {
            $Response = College::GetAllCollege();
            break;
        }
        case 'UpdateCollege': {
            $Response = College::UpdateCollege($Parms);
            break;
        }
        case 'DeleteCollege': {
            College::DeleteCollege($Parms['Id']);
            $Response = array('status' => 'R');
            break;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($Response);
?>
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the original question?