# how to add data to an sql server

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hi guys I started creating a website 2 months ago and just a week before I hit rock bottom in making it. My problem is that I can't get it to add data to my SQL database which I created using the SQL database and phpmyadmin provided with my 000webhost.com package.

Here is my PHP code with HTML at the bottom:

```
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("mysql11.000webhost.com","xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 $mysqli_query("INSERT INTO userreg (email,password,name)
 VALUES ('Peterbaob@gmail.com', 'gigtit',bob_name)");
 echo"adding is done";

 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Friend It sign up</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  css/index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
  <label class="web-name">Friend It</label>
  </ul>

  <div class="page-header">
  <h1>Sign up</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">    
  <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
  <div class="panel panel-primary" >
  <div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="panel-title">Sign up</div>                      
  </div>  
  <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

  <from action="connect.php" method="post">                              
  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  id="login-username" name="user" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="email">                                      
  </div>

  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
  <input id="login-username" type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Full Name">      
  </form>                                     
  </div>

  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
  <input id="login-password" name="pass" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

   <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i></span>
   <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordre" placeholder="Re-type Password">
   </div>                              
   <div style="margin-top:10px"  class="form-group">                                   
   <div style="margin-left:140px" class="col-sm-12 controls">
   <a  id="btn-signup" href="connect.php" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</a>                                      
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   </div>                                 
   </div>                     
   </div>  
   </div>


   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

You can also check out the website by going to [friendit.meximas.com](http://friendit.meximas.com)

Comment: check if you have given the same password generated by 000webhost...otherwise say where's an error?

Comment: sorry just a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function is `mysqli_query()` not `$mysqli_query()`, I don't know why the others did not catch this.

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO userreg (email,password,name) 
              VALUES ('Peterbaob@gmail.com', 'gigtit', 'bob_name')");
```

Since its the procedural style you can pass the connection as the first parameter:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO userreg (email,password,name) 
                    VALUES ('Peterbaob@gmail.com', 'gigtit', 'bob_name')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I think only problem is value for name column should be wrapped by single quote, which is missing.

```
 $mysqli_query("INSERT INTO userreg (email,password,name)
 VALUES ('Peterbaob@gmail.com', 'gigtit','bob_name')");
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: i tried this code but now i am receiving a new kind of error " Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/a8206989/public_html/connect.php on line 12 " you can see this error at friendit.net16.net/connect.php

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your query, try this one:

```
$mysqli_query("INSERT INTO userreg (email,password,name) 
VALUES ('Peterbaob@gmail.com', 'gigtit','bob_name')");
```

Answer (score 0):

for your second error (edit: Which you posted as a comment) its about wrong parenthesis
 you can check [PHP Error: Function name must be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611709/php-error-function-name-must-be-a-string)
or post that line which cause the error.