# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\CreateAccountT.php on line 3

Tags: php, database, authentication, unity-game-engine

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\CreateAccountT.php on line 3

```
<?php
  //Email and Password
  $Email = $_REQUEST("Email");
  $Password = $_REQUEST("Password");

  //PHP Only
  $Hostname = "localhost";
  $DBName = "accounts";
  $User = "root";
  $PasswordP = "";

  mysql_connect($Hostname, $User, $PasswordP) or die("Can't connect to DB");
  mysql_select_db($DBName) or die("Can't Connect to DB");

  if(!$Email || !$Password){
    echo"Empty";
  }else{ 
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Email = '" . $Email ."'";
    $Result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("DB Error");
    $Total = mysql_num_rows($Result);
    if($Total == 0){
        $insert = "INSERT INTO 'accounts' ('Email', 'Password') VALUES ('" . $Email . "', MDS('" . $Password . "'), 0)";
        $SQL1 = mysql_query($insert);
        echo"Success";
    }else{
        echo"AlreadyUsed";
    }
  } // End Main Else

  mysql_close();
?>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Error: Function name must be a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611709/php-error-function-name-must-be-a-string)

Comment: He's right, aditionally you have to use pdo or mysqli since the old mysql functions you are using are deprecated and highly insecure (especially the way you are using them)

Answer (score 1):

`$_REQUEST("Email")` should be `$_REQUEST["Email"]`

`$_REQUEST("Password")` should be `$_REQUEST["Password"]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[` INSTEAD OF `(`

```
$Email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
$Password = $_REQUEST["Password"];
```