# $SERVER('REMOTE_ADDR') generated the error while excuting in netbeans ide

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp

why the following code generate the error (given in buttom) in php 7 while excuting it in netbeans ide and on xamp server.

Code:

```
  <?php
  $user_ip=$_SERVER("REMOTE_ADDR");
  echo $user_ip;
```

Error:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
    C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Error: Function name must be a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611709/php-error-function-name-must-be-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER` is not a function it's an array so you'd need to do something like

```
<?php
$user_ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
echo $user_ip;
```

Comment: After executing your code I get this:                   ::1   as output

Comment: In IPv6 `::1` is the localhost IP (i.e. 127.0.0.1 equivalent in IPv4 )