# Getting this message when I try to input information into my database

Tags: php, database

This is my error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
  Function name must be a string in /home/kmsrutge/public_html/Login2process.php:5
Stack trace:
  #0 {main} thrown in /home/kmsrutge/public_html/Login2process.php on line 5
```

My code:

```
    $db_server = $mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli_error());

    $mysqli_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database: " . $mysqli_error());


    $sql = "UPDATE Invoices SET Ord_ID = '$9144' WHERE Prod_ID = '98'; ";

    $result = $mysqli_query($sql);


    if($result) echo "UPDATE success!"; else echo "UPDATE failed!";


    if($result)
    {

        echo "<p>New row was successfully inserted</p>".
        $insertQueryCount = $insertQueryCount+1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>Your insert failed.</p>";
        die($mysqli_error());
    }
?>
```

I read that it may be a possible PHP 7 issue. Any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Error: Function name must be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611709/php-error-function-name-must-be-a-string)

Comment: `$` is for variables, not functions.

Comment: Learn to read the error message.  It tells you _exactly_ which line to look at. I'm _assuming_ that line 5 is this line: `$db_server = $mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);` .  `mysqli_connect` is a function, therefore should NOT have a `$` in front of it, so should be this instead: `$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);` (NOTE: You've done that _almost everywhere_ in your code, remove the `$` from the function calls)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the result variable to the following:

```
     $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code SQL function do not start with `$` so you got the error. remove all `$` from `mysqli`.

Please change the first line:

```
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password,$db_database);
```

you don't require `mysqli_select_db` function so comment that line and check.

Also the fifth line change like `mysqli_query($db_server,$sql)`.

Please read [(https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)this documents how to connect SQL and how to write a query.